# How can I integrate database validation (queries, updates) in Ruby, Cucumber, Watir project in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, database, sql, watir

I have setup a project in RubyMine using Ruby with Cucumber, RSPEC, and Watir for UI automation of feature files. (I also have page objects implemented). In my step_definitions where the actual UI automation steps occur, I want to programatically run queries against SQL Developer to validate changes upon test completion (basic queries) and also run other updates, as needed. I would then add expect/asserts using values on UI and values from tables.

So far I have successfully setup database connections following the instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/connecting-to-a-database.html) but this operates as a separate window for connecting and running sql commands outside of my Watir tests. But what I am having trouble doing is calling this connection from within my actual tests within the step_definitions (perhaps setting up the basic connections from within an env.rb file. I have also looked into oci8 but have had trouble actually implementing this, so I am wondering if anyone can help with suggestions on pulling in database connections to Ruby/Watir code as part of the end-to-end UI automation scripts.

Example test case in RubyMine:

```
Given(/^a user goes to the main login page$/) do

  @login_page = LoginPage.new(@browser)

  @login_page.visit_new_site # Using page object
end

When(/^they enter an ID and password$/) do

  @login_page.enter_login_id('userID')

  @login_page.enter_password_id('userPassword')
end

Then(/^New web page should allow user to click Log In$/) do

  @login_page.screenshot.save("C:/robert")

  @login_page.close
  # I want to call database connection here to validate login message from table, for example
end
```

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer if you update your question to show your code and whatever errors you are getting - that way the ruby experts here will have a better idea of how to help you.

Comment: Hi Kate, the issue is that I have yet to actually implement this so there is not much to add here. I have added 'oci8' to my gemfile, in addition to 'watir','ffi','cucumber','page-object','rspec'. But my question is around how to then integrate database connectivity using oci8 or some other means. Hope this helps.